# Magento 2 : Store view will not load

Tags: magento2, multistore, no-such-entity-exception

I have 2 store views. The default view loads fine and seems to be fully operating. The added store view is failing. It also doesn't load directly by URL, it re-directs to default. My setup is 1 website > 2 Stores > 2 store views.
I am accessing the added store view with the store switcher at the bottom of the page.

I am getting this error in development mode:

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity. in /home/cityprin/public_html/citysearchlocal.com/get-found-on/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80
```

Comment: Does your 2nd store view use a different URL?

Comment: Yes main store is citysearchlocal.com/get-found-on , the other one is cityprintexpress.com/print-shop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove `genreated`, `cache` and `pub/static/*` folder then run this commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I applied this change as you suggested, now site is not working or showing css. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: I just checked your URL citysearchlocal.com/get-found-on is working fine but second URL  cityprintexpress.com/print-shop redirecting to citysearchlocal.com/get-found-on

Comment: Have you checked store view URL for 'print-shop'  in admin configuration?